# PIVOT columns in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to pivot row values as columns with no aggregation. Here is the example below

```
SampleID      TRGTNAME         CountValue
S1               K                39.5
S1               L                23.5
S1               M                -1.5
S2               K                 4.5
S2               L                 7.5
S2               M                 8.3
```

What I need is a query to return a row for each sample like below:

```
SampleID      TRGTCountValueK        TRGTCountValueL    TRGTCountValueM
S1                39.5                  23.5               -1.5
S2                 4.5                   7.5                 8.3
```

The table samp_tst contains columns (SampleID,TRGTName,CountValue)

The PIVOT action does not require aggregation. Would greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use MAX while using PIVOT  as you don't need aggregation.

with `PIVOT`, it will be like this

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *
FROM MyTable )T
PIVOT
( MAX("CountValue") for "TRGTNAME" in ('K' as TRGTNAMEK, 
                                       'L' TRGTNAMEL,
                                       'M' TRGTNAMEM))pvt
```

you can do it with case based MAX aggregation, which is similar to PIVOT

```
SELECT "SampleID",
       MAX( CASE WHEN "TRGTNAME" = 'K' THEN "CountValue" END) as TRGTCountValueK,
       MAX( CASE WHEN "TRGTNAME" = 'L' THEN "CountValue" END) as TRGTCountValueL,
       MAX( CASE WHEN "TRGTNAME" = 'M' THEN "CountValue" END) as TRGTCountValueM

FROM MyTable
GROUP BY "SampleID"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Appreciate your help